# Prove that $12 \mid n^2 - 1$ if $\gcd(n,6)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Prove that $12 \mid n^2 - 1$ if $\gcd(n,6)=1$.

I know I have to use Fermat's Little Theorem for this but I am unsure how to do this problem.

Answer (score 5):

As is mentioned in answers above, $gcd(n,6)=1$ clearly implies that $n$ is odd.  But then each of $n+1$ and $n-1$ are even, so $4$ divides $(n+1)(n-1)=n^2-1$.  Thus it is only left to show that $3$ also divides $n^2-1$.  But given any three consecutive integers, we know that $3$ must divide exactly one of them.  Applying this to $n-1,n,n+1$, and using the fact that $3$ cannot divide $n$ (since $gcd(n,6)=1$), we get the desired result.

Comment: +1 for the last part...Applying this to $n-1$,$n$,$n+1$ and using the fact that $3$ cannot divide $n$ (since $\gcd(n,6)=1)$), we get the desired result. I like how you did it without Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: Thanks!  I guess it's the result of my not being a number theorist :-)

Answer (score 4):

Can you conclude that $\gcd(n,2)=1$ and $\gcd(n,3)=1$? What about $\gcd(n,4)=1$?

Can you show that $3 \mid n^2-1$ and $4 \mid n^2-1$?   Because if yes, then you're done. Do you know why?

I leave the part $3 \mid n^2-1$ to you, because it's clear I think. Notice that if $\gcd(n,2)=1$ then $n$ must be an odd number. You can write $n^2-1=(n+1)(n-1)$ If $n$ is odd, and it must be if $\gcd(n,2)=1$ then $(n+1)$ and $(n-1)$ will both be even. so $n^2-1$ is divisible by $4$ and $4 \mid n^2-1$.

Comment: how do you know that $n^2$ -1 is divisible by 4 if ($n$ + 1) and ($n$ - 1 are both even?

Comment: @user72195 because we can write $n+1=2k$ and $n-1=2q$. If you multiply them $n^2-1 = (n+1)(n-1) = 4kq$ which means $n^2-1$ is divisible by 4. You can also say it in essentially the same way with a different appearance that if $a \mid c$ and $b \mid d$ then $ab \mid bc$. So, if $2 \mid n+1$ and $2 \mid n-1$ then $4 \mid n^2-1$.

Comment: since we know that 3 and $n$ are relativily prime to each other, is that why 3|$n^2$ - 1?

Comment: @user72195 Yes. You need $(3,n)=1$ that you can apply Fermat's little theorem. Once you know that then notice that $3|n^2-1$ is the same as $n^{3-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ and we know the later one is true because of Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: okay. So now I have concluded that 12|($n^2$-1)($n^2$-1) but how does that show 12|($n^2$-1)?

Comment: @user72195: Do you know the definition of least common multiple? If not, you'll need it. There's a theorem that if $(a,b)=1$ and $a \mid c$ and $b \mid c$ then $ab \mid c$. This comes from a more general theorem that $(a,b)[a,b]=|ab|$ where $[a,b]$ is the least common multiple of $a$ and $b$. And $(3,4)=1$, so?

Answer (score 4):

If $\gcd(n,6) = 1$, then $n$ is odd. Hence, $n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod8$. Further, $\gcd(n,3) = 1$ and hence $n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod3$. Now conclude that $n^2 \equiv1 \pmod{24}$.

Answer (score 2):

If $\gcd(6,n)=1$ then $n=6k\pm 1$. This yields $$n^2-1=36k^2\pm 12k+1-1=12k(3k\pm 1)$$ So $12\mid n^2-1$.