# If $a$ is an odd positive integer $>$ $2$ such that 3 $\not$ | $a$, then $12$ $|$ $(a^2 -$1 ))

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility

So I have the following proposal:

$a$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}_{+}$ : $a$ = $2k +1$ $>$ $2$ : 3 $\not$ |  $a$ and $>2$ then $12$ $|$ $(a^2 -$1 ).

My initial idea was to show:

$a^2 -1\equiv 0 \mod 12$

Logically it follows:

$(2k+1)^2 -1\equiv 0 \mod 12$

$4k^2 + 4k\equiv 0 \mod 12$

However I do not know where to go from here. This proof also doesn't incorporate the condition 3 $\not  |$ a . Any tips? Sorry for formatting, this is my first time using MathJax.

Comment: And also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/501895/11619) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/766700/11619). If a 50k+ user does not recognize a duplicate on the spot,...

Comment: ...they should learn about [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%2424%5Cmid%20n%5E2-1%24&p=1).

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$a^2-1=(a+1)(a-1).$$
One of the factors is a multiple of $3$, both factors are even, in fact one of them must be a multiple of $4$. Hence
$$ 24\mid a^2-1.$$

Answer (score 0):

"I do not know where to go from here. This proof also doesn't incorporate the condition 3 $\not  |$ a" You're answering your own question there. $3\nmid a$ means exactly that $k$ is neither $0,3,6$ nor $9$ modulo $12$. Now you can just check the remaining cases.

It's a bit faster if you use the Chinese remainder theorem to split modulo 12 up into a simultaneous system using modulo 3 and modulo 4 separately, but it's not necessary.